# unable to retrieve perl cgi session onto another page

Tags: perl, cgi, mod-perl

I am new to perl-cgi. I am creating session using cgi-perl and also setting cookie. but i am unable to retrieve value of session. I am also pasting the code of page1 and page2. Could anyone please edit the code and tell me where's the mistake. I am even able to store session in that directory mentioned in the code and values are also present.

Page1:

```
#!c:/perl/bin/perl.exe                           
use strict;                        
use CGI qw/:standard/;                  
use CGI::Session qw/-ip-match/;              
use CGI;                
use DBI;              
use CGI::Cookie;                    
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);                       
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";                    
print "created Session";                 
my $session = new CGI::Session(undef, undef, {Directory=>'c:/temp/session/'});                      
#setting session to expire in 1 hour                              
$session->expire("+1h");                                  
#store something                         
$session->param("value1","yakub");                             
#write to disk                                 
$session->flush();                           
my $cookie1 = new CGI::Cookie(-name=>'CGISESSID',-value=>$session->id); 
print "Set-Cookie: $cookie1\n";
```

Page2:

```
 #!c:/perl/bin/perl.exe         
 use CGI::Cookie;             
 use CGI::Session;                 
 use CGI;                
 use DBI;
 use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);                       
 print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";                      
 my $cgi = new CGI;                       
 #try to retrieve cookie.                         
 $sid = $cgi->cookie('CGISESSID') || $cgi->param('CGISESSID') || undef;                                      
 $session = load CGI::Session(undef, $sid, {Directory=>'c:/temp/session/'});                       
 $name = $session->param("value1");              
 print $name;
```

Comment: Do you receive the cookie? That would be the first thing to check.

Comment: yes i received cookie also

Comment: No, you didn't. You saw the cookie in your browser, but your browser didn't see it.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear to you, which makes your reply unclear to me. The first thing to check would be if *the Page 2 script* received the cookie. You can check this examining `$sid` in the Page 2 script.

Comment: i printed $sid and saw that my page 2 is receiving cookie but the the structure of my code was not proper as stated by innaM. Now i have rearranged and got it.Anyway...thanx for ur help

Answer (score 0):

You said in your comment that you received the cookie. This is true and false at the same time.

Your problem is the first line:

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";                    
print "created Session";                 
...
print "Set-Cookie: $cookie1\n";
```

The first thing you do is print the http-headers to the client. Then you print a lie that is not followed by a new-line and then you print another http-header line.

You need to print *all* the http-headers *first* and the print anything that is to make up the body of your response. Headers and body/content must be separated by an empty line.

(while we're at it, you might also use a less ancient style of calling methods)

```
#!c:/perl/bin/perl.exe
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw/:standard/;
use CGI::Session qw/-ip-match/;
use CGI::Cookie;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $session = CGI::Session->new(undef, undef, {Directory=>'c:/temp/session/'});

#setting session to expire in 1 hour
$session->expire("+1h");

#store something
$session->param("value1","yakub");

#write to disk
$session->flush();

my $cookie1 = CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>'CGISESSID',-value=>$session->id);

print "Set-Cookie: $cookie1\n";
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print "created Session\n";
```

Comment: Use the `header` method with the keys `-type` and `-cookie` instead of print.

Comment: thanx innaM   i got it now... i'll more careful now while coding :)